# How to convert format in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, data-conversion

I have a data file in cvs format like this:

```
StudentID  Math  Physics  Chemistry  History
001        80       90        95       98
002        99       85        90       70
003        77       80        95       90
```

The format I want is like:

```
StudentID  Math          Score
001        Math          80
001        Physics       90
001        Chemistry     95
001        History       98
002        Math          99
002        Physics       85
002        Chemistry     90
002        History       70
003        Math          77
003        Physics       80
003        Chemistry     95
003        History       90
```

How to do this format conversion in Pandas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `df.melt(id_vars='StudentID')` ?

Comment: hey @JonClements, thanks for your input. I have posted the same answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that I am recreating your `dataframe` and use the [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"StudentID":['001','002','003'],
                   "Math":[80,99,77],
                   "Physics":[90,85,80],
                   "Chemistry":[95,90,95],
                   "History":[98,70,90]})

df1 = df.melt(id_vars=['StudentID'])
```

output `df1`:

```
   StudentID   variable  value
0        001       Math     80
1        002       Math     99
2        003       Math     77
3        001    Physics     90
4        002    Physics     85
5        003    Physics     80
6        001  Chemistry     95
7        002  Chemistry     90
8        003  Chemistry     95
9        001    History     98
10       002    History     70
11       003    History     90
```

Thanks to Jon Clements for the inputs

Comment: Thank you so much, @Tamil! This is a big big help.

Answer (score 1):

Try my way....

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'history': pd.Series([3, 4,5,6]), 'math': pd.Series([5, 6,7,8])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)

df2 = df
df.drop(['ID'],axis=1)
print(df)
columns = df.columns

df_results = pd.DataFrame()
for i in columns:
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
    df_temp['ID'] = df2['ID']
    df_temp['Course']= i
    df_temp['Score']= df2[i]
    df_results  = pd.concat([df_results,df_temp])
    
print(df_results)
```

Comment: Thank you @cnp ! I did try your way. If you change the lines `df2 = df` to `df2 = df.copy()`, `df.drop(['ID'],axis=1)` to `df.drop(['ID'],axis=1, inplace=true)`, and do a sort on df_results like `df_results.sort_values(by=['ID', inplace=True)`, the results will be the exact one I look for.

Comment: Yes. It is just example. You can change something to get your target. Thank for your sharing.